# Sampling problems

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I try to enter a number into the sampling under World > gather < sampling, I can't seem to get it higher then 128, no matter if I move the leveller or manually type in the number. Why can I not do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 128 is the max. https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/lighting/ambient_occlusion.html#gather When you set it to 128 it is really 16,384, that number is squared.